# Will the Mac Mini late-2012 try to reformat dual PC raid discs when I plug them in?

Tags: mac-mini, raid

I have a new Mac Mini late 2012 model replacing a PC with dual 2 TB hard drives set up in Raid format mirrored and auto save.

I want to put them into a caddy, a Startech 4-bay SATA version with a view to eventually adding 2 more as separate drives but for now I need to know whether it will try and reformat these discs when plugged in as there's 1.3 GB of data on each that isn't backed up elsewhere!

I could buy an external drive to save the data to but seems a waste of money if this will work without affecting the existing files.

Does anyone know for sure either way please or if there's a way of making sure they work?

Answer (score 1):

If it can't read them, it will ask you if you want to reformat them. It won't reformat anything automatically.